# Can you explain how to respond to this type of question and what is the grammatical name for such a question?

Tags: questions, tag-questions

> You didn't go to the shops, did you?

Can you explain how to respond to this type of question and what is the grammatical name for such a question?

Comment: The bit on the end "did you?" is called a 'tag question' (or 'interrogative tag'). The usual response would be something like "Yes, I did", or "No, I didn't".

Comment: @BillJ Isn't that an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question). If you didn't go to the shops, you would say "No", and if you did, you could say "Yes." But often it's clearer to say something like "No, I didn't", or "Yes, actually I did."

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a yes/no or true/false type question. It also sort of duplicates itself. Another way to say it, You went to the shops, yes or no? In general, Did you or did you not do x?